# Monotonicity in this argmin function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following function:
$$f(a)=\text{argmin}_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2}(1-a)(b_i-t)^2+a| b_i-t |\right\}\quad ,a\in[0,1]$$

Is there a way to show that the function is monotone in $a$?

Edit: for $a=0$ we have the mean of $\beta_i$s and for $a=1$ we have the median. I'm interested in the cases when $a\in(0,1)$, in particular that the function is bounded by the mean and median.

Comment: $t$ seems to shift from the median to the mean. Could it formulate as a quadratic optimization problem with linear constraints and state the KKT conditions?

Comment: @madnessweasley I'm aware. I did not get a answer then hence I'm asking it again now.

Comment: @ChuckP The one answer in the link above shows that you need to define your question better (as stated, it doesn't make complete sense).

Comment: I've made the modification now to more accurately represent what I want to know.